# How to get Raphael XML string in Explorer 8?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have a function that turns the Raphael svg into a PNG.  It works for everything IE9+, Firefox and Chrome.  The problem is that a lot of our clients still use IE8 and cannot upgrade b/c they still use Windows XP. What I need is to emulate this functionality for IE8:

```
  var svgElement = document.body.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
  var svgXml= (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svgElement);
  var finalSvg = svgXml.FixForRaphael();
```

The problem is that in IE8 document.body.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0] is "undefined" and that XMLSerializer is not in IE8 either.  The latter I believe I have solved for, but I still cannot figure out how to solve the first.  When I alert(svgElement) in Firefox it says it is a "Object SVGSVGElement".  How do I get this object in IE8?

Comment: Try Raphael toSVGString export plugin in conjunction with canvg library and FlashCanvas.

Comment: Also, if I may, isn't your question as simple as how to convert Raphael paper to PNG image in VML based browsers?

Comment: In IE8 and lower Raphaël produces VML, not SVG. https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.Export (mentioned above) seems like a good candidate.